# react-navigation pass props to a class component

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Assume I have the following code snippet to create a `DrawerNavigator`

```
export const DrawerApp = DrawerNavigator({
    PageHome: {
        screen: InboxScreen
    },
},
{
    contentComponent: props => <RightMenuScreen />,
    drawerPosition: 'right'
});
```

I read from sample [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/Drawer.js) that I can pass props like a `banner` prop to a functional component using syntax like

```
const MyNavScreen = ({ navigation, banner }) => (<View><Text>{banner}</Text></View>);
// ...
// ...
// ...
const InboxScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
    <MyNavScreen banner={'InboxScreen'} navigation={navigation} />
);
```

But what if I declare my Component using class Component, how do I archive the same behaviour of passing my custom prop to the `MyNavScreen`

```
class InboxScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        // here I want to get a prop like `banner` or `callback` from props
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using **this.props** you can achieve the same

```
class InboxScreen  extends Component{
static navigationOptions = {
  drawerLabel: 'Inbox',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <MaterialIcons
      name="move-to-inbox"
      size={24}
      style={{ color: tintColor }}
    />
  ),
};
render (){
  return(
  <MyNavScreen banner={'Inbox Screen'} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
  );
}
}
```